# Propagar evento javascript

Tags: javascript

Cuando arrastro el bloque pero haciendo click sobre la imagen del div, es la imagen la que se arrastra y no el bloque entero (y por lo tanto no funciona el drop) , quiero que cuando arrastres la imagen se propague el evento y sea el div entero el que se arrastre, este es el codigo HTML:

```
<div class="item" id="i1">
    <img src="img/camiseta1.jpg" alt="descripción i1"/>
    <label class="title">Camiseta 1</label>
    <label class="price">20 €</label>
    <label class="stock">Stock 10</label>
</div>
```

Esto es el Javascript

```
var producto = document.getElementById('i1');
producto.draggable = true;
producto.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
```

Comment: corrige getElementById

Comment: Y si le ponnes `draggable` false a la imagen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta que obtengas un handler a la imagen, y le des atributo `draggable = false`. Con eso, draguear la camiseta arrastra todo el div.

```js
var drag=function() {
  console.log('empezó el drag');
};

var producto = document.getElementById('i1');
producto.draggable = true;
producto.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);

var camiseta = document.getElementById('camiseta1');
camiseta.draggable = false;
```

```css
.item {
border:1px solid green;
text-align:center;
float:left;
}
.item img {
width:150px;
height:150px;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" id="i1">
    <img id="camiseta1"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Naranja-Caballo-al-estilo-de-dibujos-animados-Camisetas-ninos.png/220px-Naranja-Caballo-al-estilo-de-dibujos-animados-Camisetas-ninos.png" alt="descripción i1"/>
    <label class="title">Camiseta 1</label>
    <label class="price">20 €</label>
    <label class="stock">Stock 10</label>
</div>
```